# convert cell array with mix double and single to only double

Tags: matlab

I'm using an API that returns cell array with double and single data; therefore, I'm not able to use `cell2mat()` so I can manipulate data using vector operator like vectorization. This is a minimal working example,

```
a = single(1);
b = double(2);
c = double(3);
d = single(4);
e = single(5);

data = {a,b,c,d,e};

cell2mat(data)
```

I have two questions. First, how can I access the numbers in the cell array using colon operator like `data{1:3}`? If this is not possible, how can I convert all data to double so I can use `cell2mat`?

Comment: Use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the function `double` to each array in the cell array.